# What is the definition of "non-ladder" or "non-run"?

Tags: meaning

I found this word in a dictionary (my native language to English), but I cannot find it in any English one.

Comment: What word was it representing in your native language? It probably refers to ladies tights/pantyhose. A _ladder_ in this sense is when a few broken threads in a stocking cause the knitted fabric to unravel upwards from the hole. There are ways of making the fabric so that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

When referring to tights and stockings, a ladder, or a run is when you get a small hole, and the knitting below hole comes undone. Because the threads get stretched straight it looks like the rungs of a ladder.  Because the damage tends to spread we say that it "runs down the tight.

[image]

[Source](https://extra.ie/2017/11/29/news/extraordinary/this-simple-hack-will-stop-your-tights-from-laddering)

So "non-ladder" or "non-run" tights are those that are resistant to ladders, either because the thread is stronger, or the knit can tear without laddering.