# What does it mean when tights or stockings have runs?

Tags: word-usage

What does it mean when tights or stockings have runs?

For example:

> her tights have runs.

Can we use the same word for socks?

Comment: "a long, vertical hole in tights and stockings"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the definition of "non-ladder" or "non-run"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237308/what-is-the-definition-of-non-ladder-or-non-run) It's not a perfect dupe, but the answer there also answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pictures:
[Google images "runs in stockings"](https://www.google.com/search?q=runs%20in%20stockings&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ0aCd9N_tAhUQK80KHb35DZkQ_AUoAXoECBkQAw&biw=1386&bih=769#imgrc=VWMf6R2T1PyC5M)

They are also called "ladders".

If it looks like that, or if it involves threads coming loose, you can use the same word for socks or other garments.

Comment: Can we use the same word for socks?

Comment: @coolguy it's hard to make runs in socks, they aren't that stretchy, you usually have holes

Comment: @coolguy  I adde to my answer.